# Parse value contained in data elem to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

In javascript, I'm rendering a list of data points like so:

```
<ul class="site-stats">
   <li>   
      <div data-title="Cleared Orders" data-pts="[gd(2013, 9 , 9), 3],[gd(2013, 9 , 10), 1],[gd(2013, 9 , 13), 1],[gd(2013, 9 , 16), 1]" class="cc">
                   <i class="icon=arrow-right"></i>
                   <strong>6</strong> 
                   <small>Cleared Orders</small>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li>
               <div data-title="Customers Added" data-pts="[gd(2013, 9 , 9), 5],[gd(2013, 9 , 10), 2]" class="cc">
                   <i class="icon=arrow-right"></i>
                   <strong>7</strong> 
                   <small>Customers Added</small>
               </div>
   </li>
   <li>
               <div data-title="Counts Ran" data-pts="[gd(2013, 9 , 9), 8],[gd(2013, 9 , 10), 11],[gd(2013, 9 , 11), 7],[gd(2013, 9 , 12), 1],[gd(2013, 9 , 16), 5]" class="cc">
                   <i class="icon=arrow-right"></i>
                   <strong>32</strong> 
                   <small>Counts Ran</small>
               </div>
   </li>
   <li>
               <div data-title="Pending Orders" data-pts="" class="cc">
                   <i class="icon=arrow-right"></i>
                   <strong>0</strong> 
                   <small>Pending Orders</small>
               </div>
   </li>
   <li>
               <div data-title="Failed Orders" data-pts="" class="cc">
                   <i class="icon=arrow-right"></i>
                   <strong>0</strong> 
                   <small>Failed Orders</small>
               </div>
   </li>
   <li>
               <div data-title="Records Delivered" data-pts="[gd(2013, 9 , 9), 25970],[gd(2013, 9 , 10), 2500],[gd(2013, 9 , 13), 2023],[gd(2013, 9 , 16), 400]" class="cc">
                   <i class="icon=arrow-right"></i>
                   <strong>30893</strong> 
                   <small>Records Delivered</small>
               </div>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

Basically, data-pts holds my values for a flot chart.  Onclick I want to change the contents of my flot chart as such:

```
$(".cc").click(function(e)
    {
        var data = $(this).data('pts');
        console.log(data);
        plot.setData([data]);
        plot.setupGrid();
        plot.draw();

    });
```

When I do this, the var data is returning as a straight up string... what is REALLY weird, is the console.log(data) gives me the array I expect.  Of course, this results in the flot chart not refreshing with the new data... is there away for me to convert the string I'm getting back into a raw javascript array?  I'm open to other suggestions as well...

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of the array you expect ?

Comment: Sure, this works:  var data = [[gd(2013, 9, 9), 25970], [gd(2013, 9, 10), 2500], [gd(2013, 9, 13), 2023], [gd(2013, 9, 16), 400]];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you got is a string. You could use `eval()` to evaluate the string and convert it to an object.

```
var data = $(this).data('pts');
data = eval(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
$(function(){
    $(".cc").click(function(e)
    {
        var data = $(this).data('pts');
        if(data.length) {
            var reg = /\]\,\[/;
            var matches = data.replace('[','').substring(0, data.length-2).split(reg);
            var arr = [];
            arr = matches.map(function(i){
                var a = [];
                a[0] = i.substring(0, i.lastIndexOf(','));
                a[1] = i.substring(i.lastIndexOf(' ')+1);
                return a;
            });

            console.log(arr[0][0]); // gd(2013, 9 , 9)
            console.log(arr[0][1]); // 3
            console.log(arr[3][0]); // gd(2013, 9 , 16)
            console.log(arr[3][1]); // 1
        }
    });
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/6SFQ8/)
Also, `eval(data)` will evaluate your function calls, all together.